# Scala: How to inherit the same trait twice?

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

I'm following along in Odersky's "Programming in Scala" 2nd edition, and in section 12.5 "Traits as stackable modifications", he presents an `IntQueue` along with a trait that doubles any values you insert into the queue:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
abstract class IntQueue {
 def get(): Int
 def put(x: Int)
}

class BasicIntQueue extends IntQueue {
 private val buf = new ArrayBuffer[Int]
 def get() = buf.remove(0)
 def put(x: Int) { buf += x }
}

trait Doubling extends IntQueue {
 abstract override def put(x: Int) {
  super.put(2 * x)
 }
}
```

The book then shows that you can instantiate a queue which doubles every integer you insert into it via `new BasicIntQueue with Doubling`. What I wanted to do was created a similar queue which multiplies every integer by 4, like this: `new BasicIntQueue with Doubling with Doubling`. However, this triggers a compile error "`trait Doubling is inherited twice`". Looking into this, I guess this has something to do with the limitations of linearlization; specifically that a given trait cannot appear twice in the linearlization of a class hierarchy.

What's the best way, then, to achieve the effect I want?

Here's a bit more information on my "real world" use case, in case the answer depends on this:

I have a class `SoundFile`, which reads a .wav file, and yields a `SoundFile` object, which extends a `WaveForm` trait. The `SoundFile` class is analogous to the `BasicIntQueue` above, and the `WaveForm` trait is analogous to the `IntQueue` above.

I have 2 traits that are analogous to `Doubling`, one called `Echo` and one called `Reverse`.

I wanted to write `new SoundFile("myFile.wav") with Reverse with Echo with Reverse`, but I ran into that same compile error about inheriting from the `Reverse` trait twice.

Comment: Does the JVM have that limitation?  Java does; no class can implement the same interface twice.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the JVM had that limitation, but without knowing all the details of how Scala implements its many features on the JVM, I don't see why Scala couldn't generate bytecode that "does the right thing".

E.g. If you ask whether that anonymous class was an instance of `Doubling`, it'd reply `true`, because it IS true; no need to make the fact that it inherits twice apparent in the type system.

Comment: Interesting question.  Emphasizes that traits are less "layers" and more "mixin".  Traits are not wrappers, are not a "function applied to a class/interface to create a new class/interface".

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you can't inherit from the same trait twice.  Instead you should use some other mechanism.  For instance, `Reverse` and `Echo` are both manipulations of the waveform.  You could have

```
val reverse = (w: Waveform) => // produce a reverse waveform
val echo =    (w: Waveform) => // copy the waveform onto itself with delay
new SoundFile("myFile.wav", reverse andThen echo andThen reverse)
```

or somesuch.

If you require more changes than just a simple function, you'll have to encapsulate the modifications to functionality in your own class:

```
trait Transform { self =>
  def apply(w: Waveform): Waveform
  def time: Double
  def andThen(t: Transform) = new Transform {
    def apply(w: Waveform) = t(self(w))
    def time = self.time + t.time
  }
}
val reverse = new Transform { def time = 0.0; def apply ... }
val echo    = new Transform { def time = 1.0; def apply ... }
// Same deal after here
```